# Using Distinct with joins

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I created join what gives me around  3 000 000 count(*), but I know I only need count(*) around 700 000 and that count comes from table cr.OBJ_Daily_Offers odo
I need to get values by that table PK what is odo.obj_dailyoffers_id.
what came to my mind is to use distinct, but I dont't know how to get allso count(*) to see if the result is as on daily_offers table.
My select needs to be somthing like this.

```
select distinct odo.OBJ_DAILYOFFERS_ID, *
from cr.obj_daily_offers odo
join cr.obj_val v
    on v.obj_row_id = odo.schedule_id
join cr.OBJ_VAL_OBJ_VAL l on l.OBJ_VAL_OBJ_VAL_ID = v.OBJ_VAL_ID
join cr.OBJ_VAL v1 on v1.OBJ_VAL_ID = l.LINKVALUE_OBJ_VAL_ID
join cr.OBJ_ROW a on a.OBJ_ROW_ID = v1.OBJ_ROW_ID 
join cr.OBJ_VAL v2 on v2.OBJ_ROW_ID = v1.OBJ_ROW_ID and v2.OBJ_FIELD_ID = 750 
join cr.OBJ_VAL v3 on v3.VAL = v2.VAL
join cr.OBJ_ROW a1 on a1.OBJ_ROW_ID = v3.OBJ_ROW_ID and a1.OBJ_ID = 752 
join cr.OBJ_VAL v4 on v4.OBJ_ROW_ID = v3.OBJ_ROW_ID and v4.OBJ_FIELD_ID = 810
```

Comment: If you need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` when you do `SELECT *`, there's probably something weird with your db design... Add a date filter to the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: This db is not built logically that's why I have to use something to bypass the idiotic approach

Comment: OR do I need to do this query by "group by" and having count(*) >1 ?